# Magento2: I'm getting empty data from the product attribute

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, php

I am receiving empty data from the product attribute "product_types"
& getting a null value when fetching the data from this attribute.

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1. Please check the machine name of "product_type" is correct.
2. `getAttributeText` may return array. You cannot use echo directly.

Answer (score 0):

> **Please enable the setting below in your custom attribute.**

[image]

> **Afterward, you need to run the command below, and then you will get the value on the frontend.**

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento in:rein
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento cache:clean
```